# How to continue running scripts defined in package.json in case one fails?

Tags: javascript, node.js, package.json, webdriver-io, npm-scripts

I have this in package.json file:

```
{
 "name": "test demo",
 "version": "1.0.0",
 "description": "test demo scripts",
 "scripts": {
   "test:v1": "wdio src/resources/config/wdio.chrome.conf.js --spec test/Tests.spec.ts",
   "test:v2": "wdio src/resources/config/wdio.firefox.conf.js --spec test/Tests.spec.ts",

   "test": "npm run test:v1 && npm run test:v2"
   },

    ...
}
```

When run this command:

```
npm run test
```

then if `test:v1` fails, then `test:v2` script is not executed at all.
Is there a way to configure this so that all scripts run regardless if some of them failed?

EDIT:
When I try this in package.json:

```
"test": "npm run test:v1 ; npm run test:v2"
```

Then I still don't get both scripts executed, just `test:v1` gets executed with error.
This is what I get in the console:

```
C:\2020\demo>npm run test

> demo@1.0.0 test C:\2020\demo
> npm run test:v1 ; npm run test:v2

> demo@1.0.0 test:v1 C:\2020\demo
> wdio src/resources/config/wdio.chrome.conf.js --spec test/Tests.spec.ts ";" 
  "npm" "run" "test:v2"

Execution of 1 spec files started at 2020-06-12T15:16:42.936Z

[0-0] RUNNING in chrome - C:\2020\demo\Tests.spec.ts

... other log with failing tests ...

Spec Files:      0 passed, 1 failed, 1 total (100% completed) in 00:00:27

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! demo@1.0.0 test:v1: `wdio src/resources/config/wdio.chrome.conf.js --spec test/Tests.spec.ts ";" "npm" "run" "test:v2"`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the demo@1.0.0 test:v1 script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional 
logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\<User>\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-06- 
12T15_17_10_512Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! demo@1.0.0 test: `npm run test:v1 ; npm run test:v2`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the demo@1.0.0 test script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional 
logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\<User>\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-06- 
12T15_17_10_548Z-debug.log
```

If I try like this in package.json:

```
"test": "npm run test:v1; npm run test:v2"
```

Then I get this in the console:

```
npm ERR! missing script: test:v1;
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Did you mean one of these?
npm ERR!     test:v1
npm ERR!     test:v2
```

Thanks!

Comment: If you run `npm config get script-shell` which shell does it report? Does it report either: **1)** `sh` - which is the default shell that npm utilizes for running npm scripts on _*nix_ platforms. **2)** Or does it report `cmd.exe` - which is the default shell that npm utilizes for running npm scripts on _Windows_ platforms. If it's the later, i.e. if it's `cmd.exe`, then change your `test` script to utilize a single ampersand, for instance: `"test": "npm run test:v1 & npm run test:v2"`.

Comment: @RobC thanks for the comment! This is what I get:
`C:\Program Files\nodejs>npm config get script-shell
null
C:\Program Files\nodejs>npm config get shell
C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe`

Comment: Yes so you're using Windows and the default shell that npm scripts utilizes is `cmd.exe` - that's why when you try using a semi-colon (`;`) - as per _@gzcz_ answer it doesn't work. The semi-colon (`;`) would meet your requirement on _*nix_ platforms (Linux, macOS etc) because npm utilizes `sh` as the shell for npm scripts. As per my first comment you need to try using the [single ampersand (`&`)](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html).  For instance: `"test": "npm run test:v1 & npm run test:v2"`

Comment: @RobC Thanks a lot man! it helped. It works with `&`. Can you please add a comment as an answer so I can accept it :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution for this differs depending on which OS you are using because NPM utilizes a different shell for running npm scripts.

- On **nix*, (Linux, macOS, etc..), the default shell that npm utilizes for running npm scripts is `sh`.
- On Windows the default shell that npm utilizes for running npm scripts is `cmd.exe`.

---

#### Check which shell npm is using?

Using the [npm config](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/config) command you need to check the value of the [`script-shell`](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config#script-shell) setting. To do this you can run the following command:

```
npm config get script-shell
```

It will typically return/print either the pathname to `cmd.exe` or `sh` - depending on which OS your using.

---

### Solution:

1. **If you're running Windows and the default shell is `cmd.exe`**

   Then change your `test` script in *package.json* to the following:

   ```
   "test": "npm run test:v1 & npm run test:v2"
   ```

   Note the double ampersand (`&&`) has been replace with a single ampersand (`&`).

Or...

2. **If you're running **nix* and the default shell is `sh`**

   Then change your `test` script in *package.json* to the following:

   ```
   "test": "npm run test:v1; npm run test:v2"
   ```

   Note the double ampersand (`&&`) has been replace with a single semi-colon (`;`).

Answer (score 2):

```
npm run test:v1; npm run test:v2
```

`;` means run the next command regardless of the success of the previous one.

`&&` means only run the next command if the previous one succeeded.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I edited my question with what I have tried based on your comment. Unfortunately it didn't work. Only first script was executed and after it failed the other one was not started.

Comment: You can use [concurrently](https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently). Run `npm install concurrently` to install then in your package.json scripts you can do `"test": "concurrently \"npm run test:v1\" \"npm run test:v2\""`. This will basically run the two test commands concurrently.