# NPM and How to run all sequential commands even if one command fails

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-scripts

I have an npm script where one of the commands, in this case, the `test` script, can fail.

```
"test": "npm run init && npm run test && npm run end"
```

If the `test` script fails the `end` script is never executed.
Is there a way to force the execution of the `end` script even if `test` fails?
Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to continue running scripts defined in package.json in case one fails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62343768/how-to-continue-running-scripts-defined-in-package-json-in-case-one-fails)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `;` control operator:

```sh
npm run init ; npm run test ; npm run end
```

`;` means execute the preceding statement and, after it completes, proceed to the next statement.

Comment: Does this not also not change the exit code? Now the exit code is only reliant on the exit code from the last command as opposed from any of them. 

In other words, if the first command fails, but the last succeeds, it will possibly misleadingly report a success.