# npm scripts: chaining commands with && works, but fails with ;

Tags: npm, npm-scripts

Having a strange issue here with npm (on Windows, if it matters).

Chaining two commands with `&&` works fine:

```
"test:integration": "firebase emulators:exec --non-interactive \"npm run test:integration:runner\" && kill-port 9000",
```

But if I substitute `;` for `&&` it fails to work:

```
"test:integration": "firebase emulators:exec --non-interactive \"npm run test:integration:runner\" ; kill-port 9000",
```

Instead of running the first command successfully, `npm run test:integration` just returns immediately if I use `;`.

I want to run `kill-port 9000` as cleanup after the first command, regardless of the exit status from the first command, which is why I switched to `;`.

Any idea what's going on here? Is there an alternative way I can do this besides using `;`?

(I did get it working by chanining `&&` and `||` like `(first_command && kill-port 9000) || kill-port 9000`, but that seems hackish and I would like to understand why `;` isn't working)

Comment: The shell npm utilizes to run npm scripts on Win is `cmd` by default. However on _*nix_ (Linux, macOS, ...) it utilizes `sh` as the default shell to run npm scripts. As you’re using Win, (essentially using `cmd` when running npm scripts), then consider substituting the semicolon (`;`) with the AND operator, i.e. a single ampersand (`&`). Note: the AND operator in `cmd` (`&`) has the same logic as the semicolon (`;`) in `sh` on _*nix_ - which is essentially execute  _command 2_ regardless of whether _command 1_ fails or succeeds.

Comment: However, be mindful that the AND operator (`&`) has a different meaning/logic in `sh` on _*nix_.

Comment: Ooh, that's interesting, but I definitely don't like how &  is system dependent. It's surprising that it wasn't abstracted by nom. Anyhow, if you post this as an answer I'll gladly accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The shell that npm utilizes to run npm scripts on Windows is `cmd` by default. However on **nix* (Linux, macOS, ...) it utilizes `sh` as the default shell to run npm scripts.

As you’re using Windows, (essentially using `cmd` when running npm scripts), then consider substituting the semicolon (`;`) with the AND operator, i.e. a single ampersand (`&`).

The AND operator in `cmd` (`&`) has the same logic as the semicolon (`;`) in `sh` on **nix* - which is essentially execute *command 2* regardless of whether *command 1* fails or succeeds.

**Notes:**

1. Be mindful that the AND operator (`&`) has a different meaning/logic in `sh` on **nix*.
2. FYI, I answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62343768/how-to-continue-running-scripts-defined-in-package-json-in-case-one-fails/62348702#62348702).

Comment: Thanks again! Powershell supports ;, and it looks like it's possible to change the shell npm uses on WIndows (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23243353/how-to-set-shell-for-npm-run-scripts-in-windows), but I think I'm going to stick with my `||` and `&&` composition for now.

Comment: You’re welcome... yes that’s wise,`(first_command && kill-port 9000) || kill-port 9000` yields the desired result with `sh` or `cmd` regardless of how _"hackish"_ it may feel.